# Define the marker and color setting by the dataset label

Tags: python, matplotlib

I think my target was simple. But I haven't check out my hidden mistake somewhere.

I was learning PLA(Perceptron Linear Algorithm) and tried to achieve it in Python language.

The algorithm itself has been work out. Then, I want to plot the adjust process through the algorithm.

#### The dataset

```
dataset = np.array([
((1, -0.4, 0.3), -1),
((1, -0.3, -0.1), -1),
((1, -0.2, 0.4), -1),
((1, -0.1, 0.1), -1),
((1, 0.9, -0.5), 1),
((1, 0.7, -0.9), 1),
((1, 0.8, 0.2), 1),
((1, 0.2, -0.6), 1)])
```

> #### I want to plot the scatter point with different style by the label("-1" or "1" in this example)

So, here is what I coded:

```
def marker_choice(s):
    if s == 1:
        marker = "o"
    else:
        marker = "x"  
    return marker

def color_choice(s):
    if s == 1:
        color = "r"
    else:
        color = "b"  
    return color  


ps = [v[0] for v in dataset]
label = [v[1] for v in dataset]

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot()  

ax.scatter([v[1] for v in ps], [v[2] for v in ps], s=80, \
           c=color_choice(v for v in np.array(label)), 
           marker=marker_choice(v for v in np.array(label)),
       )
```

[image]

#### Target

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your one line loops don't produce your required output. If you just run them to test their output then the result is color:`'b'` and marker:`'x'` which explains why your output is the way it is.

The solution below does not use one line loops but does produce the required graph. One thing to note is that the markers on the output from the code below are the wrong way around to that in your desired output in the question. This is simply a case of altering the `marker_choice(s)` function and changing `if s==1` to `if s == -1`.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

dataset = np.array([
((1, -0.4, 0.3), -1),
((1, -0.3, -0.1), -1),
((1, -0.2, 0.4), -1),
((1, -0.1, 0.1), -1),
((1, 0.9, -0.5), 1),
((1, 0.7, -0.9), 1),
((1, 0.8, 0.2), 1),
((1, 0.2, -0.6), 1)])

def marker_choice(s):
    if s == 1:       # change to -1 here to get the markers the other way around
        marker = "o"
    else:
        marker = "x"
    return marker

def color_choice(s):
    if s == 1:
        color = "r"
    else:
        color = "b"
    return color

ps = [v[0] for v in dataset]
label = [v[1] for v in dataset]

str_label = []
str_marker = []

for i in (label):
    a = color_choice(label[i])
    str_label.append(a)
    b = marker_choice(label[i])
    str_marker.append(b)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

for i in range (len(ps)):
    data = ps[i]
    data_x = data[1]
    data_y = data[2]
    ax.scatter(data_x,data_y, s=80, color = str_label[i], marker=str_marker[i])

plt.show()
```

This produces the output below:

[image]

*Note:* I have not tested how the performance of this code compares to your original code.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think the performance of those two code would be comparative  due to the small-scale dataset.